# How to copy a postgres table from one DB to another, on another server, which uses sequences

Tags: postgresql

I have a DB on server1, and in the DB I have a Table (table1), and an associated sequence (seq1).

table1 uses the sequence to generate a sequential ID, which is a field in the table. i.e.

```
\d table1

                               Table "public.table1"
```

Column  |   Type            | Collation | Nullable |         Default

--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------

id       | integer           |           | not null |nextval('seq1'::regclass)

hostname | character varying |           |          |

location | character varying |           |          |

So when I add a new record of hostname, location, the id field is automatically populated with the next sequence number.

I want to copy table1 to a DB on another server, but I want to maintain the current sequence numbers in the table. (These sequence numbers are referenced from another table so they need to be maintained as they are). Once it's copied over to the new DB I will re-create the sequence, starting from the highest id in Table1 + 1.

At the moment table1 doesn't exist on the new server, so I want to copy over the schema and the data.

I'm a little worried if I just do a pg_dump, and then restore using psql, I'll lose the existing sequence numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: You won't and it is easy enough to test, use `pg_dump -d the_db -t the_table -U some_user -f some_file.sql`.

Comment: I forgot to mention the DB I am trying to copy to is on a remote server.  I'm trying psql --dbname=TheDB --host=RemoteServer --username=me  some_file.sql but its ignoring the some_file.sql

Comment: Assuming you created `some_file.sql` using the `pg_dump` command I showed then: `psql --dbname=TheDB --host=RemoteServer --username=me  -f some_file.sql`

Comment: Fab. It all worked as you described. Even with sequences. And with multiple tables. Thanks!